# Check if sum of subarray is a multiple of target

Tags: python, sub-array

I encountered this problem, where I have to check if there exists a subarray sum that is a multiple of a target value, and if the length of the subarray is at least 2.

I've looked at one of the solution, which is below

```
class Solution():
    def checkSubarraySum(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        dic = {0:-1}
        summ = 0
        for i, n in enumerate(nums):
            if k != 0:
                summ = (summ + n) % k
            else:
                summ += n
            if summ not in dic:
                dic[summ] = i
            else:
                if i - dic[summ] >= 2:
                    return True
        return False
```

What I don't understand is why it is "i - dic[summ] >= 2" instead of greater or equal to 1? I assume it is checking whether the length is greater than 2, so wouldn't the difference of two indexes plus one be the length of the subarray?

Comment: It's comparing the distance between two indexes, to see if it's at least 2. That said, the algorithm implementation may or may not be correct (I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

Since all the elements in `nums` are either 0 or positive, the condition `summ in dic` (else of `summ not in dic`) and `i - dic[summ] >= 2` only satisfy when the line `summ = (summ + n) % k` is run in the same iteration. The reason we need to check why it's `>=2` and not `>=1` is because the index in `dic[summ]` is not included in the subarray so `i - dic[summ]` is to check if the size of the continuous subarray is at least 2